# A tag for duckduckgo?

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are [some questions about DuckDuckGo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=duckduckgo), but [no tag for it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo).

I do not have enough reputation to create it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It now exists](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo). Please do take the time to fill out its guidance and only add it to appropriate questions.